# Creating a Custom Handler for "torch-model-archiver" to Generate a Model .mar File

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, pipeline, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Here is my model

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28 * 28, 512, dtype=torch.float),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits
```

I am following this repo for crate pipeline: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/training/pytorch_gcs_data_training.ipynb

I'm currently working on a project that involves deploying a PyTorch model using the "torch-model-archiver" tool. While I understand the basic process of using "torch-model-archiver" to create a .mar file, I'm facing some challenges with the default handler provided by the tool.

I'm not quite sure how to implement this. Could someone please guide me on how to create a custom handler for "torch-model-archiver"? I want to generate a .mar file for my PyTorch model using this custom handler.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [notebook here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/community-content/pytorch_pre_built_images_deployment/pytorch-text-classification-vertex-ai-deploy.ipynb) that shows how to add a custom handler and package it using torch model archiver.

The steps are

1. Create [Torch custom handler](https://pytorch.org/serve/custom_service.html#custom-handler-with-class-level-entry-point) to add pre/post-process logic with prediction logic following
2. Run torch model archiver with custom handler as additional dependency

```
torch-model-archiver -f \
  --model-name=model \
  --version=1.0 \
  --serialized-file=$LOCAL_TRAINED_MODEL_DIRECTORY/pytorch_model.bin \
  --handler=$PREDICTOR_DIRECTORY/custom_handler.py \
  --extra-files ... \
  --export-path=$ARCHIVED_MODEL_PATH
```